# In knockout js, text in select is not changing when button click?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, single-page-application

In my spa, I am using knock out js to bind data from api to select option successfully.

Code:

```
<select id="ddlClassificationPosition" name="" data-theme="c" data-bind="options: ClassificationPositionData, optionsValue: 'ClassificationPositionID', optionsText: function (i) { return i.Classification + ':' + i.Position },selectedOptions: SelectedItems, optionsCaption: 'Choose..'">
 <option value="0">
     Choose..
 </option>               
</select>

 self.SelectedItems= ko.observableArray([]);
  var vm = {
        ClassificationPositionData: ko.observableArray(positionData),
        ClassificationPositionID: ko.observable(),
        SelectedItems: ko.observableArray([])
    };
```

But in refresh button click, I want to change the selected option to default text "Choose..". I wrote the given below code in button click.

```
 <a data-role="button" data-transition="slide" href="#page3" data-icon="arrow-r"
              data-iconpos="right" data-bind="event: { click: btnAddContactLink }">
                 Sample
              </a>
self.btnAddContactLink = function () {
   self.SelectedItems.removeAll();
}
```

After refresh button click, it doesn't change the text. But if i click that dropdown, then it showing "Choose.." as selected option like given below.
[image]

I don't know where I made mistake. Please help me friends

Comment: Please do not edit all context and code out of your question. Doing this just makes it useless to future visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Radio button code:

```
  <input id="radio1" name="rbtnShift" value="1" data-theme="c" type="radio">
```

In refresh button click, please write like given below:

```
  $("input[type='radio']").checkboxradio();
  $("input[name^='rbtnShift']").attr("checked", false).checkboxradio("refresh");
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use jQuery like that to manipulate the DOM. Try to manipulate the view model directly and let Knockout handle UI updates for you. You need to use the `selectedOptions` binding to do so.

Assuming this view model:

```
var vm = {
    ClassificationPositionData: ko.observableArray([i1, i2]),
    ClassificationPositionID: ko.observable(),
    SelectedItems: ko.observableArray([])
};
```

You can change your `select`'s `data-bind` to the following:

```html
<select id="ddlClassificationPosition" name="" data-theme="c" 
        data-bind="options: ClassificationPositionData, 
                   optionsValue: 'ClassificationPositionID', 
                   optionsText: function (i) { return i.Classification + ':' + i.Position }, 
                   selectedOptions: SelectedItems,
                   optionsCaption: 'Choose..'">
</select>
```

This will bind the selected items to an observable in your view model. Then use the following method to refresh and reset to the base option:

```
vm.refresh = function() { vm.SelectedItems.removeAll(); };
```

See all this at work in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X7jy7/).

PS: I don't think you'll need the explicit `option` element if you also have a binding for `optionsCaption`.

Comment: Hi Jeroen, really thanks alot for your reply. but your coding is not working for me. I don't know why. I changed my coding as per yours.I got below error Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: SelectedItems is not defined;
Bindings value: options: ClassificationPositionData, optionsValue: 'ClassificationPositionID', optionsText: function (i) { return i.Classification + ':' + i.Position }, selectedOptions: SelectedItems, optionsCaption: 'Choose..'

Comment: Did you create a `SelectedItems` observable as a sibling (to ClassificationPositionData et al) property on your view model? Perhaps it would help if you extended your question with the relevant bits of your view model.

Comment: Yes. I created as like this  self.SelectedItems= ko.observableArray([]);. but its not working for me. if i made any mistake, please tell me. If possible please update code for me. Because i'm beginner for knockout js.

Comment: Hmm, don't think it's *me* that has to update code (my fiddle is working), rather *you* should include more code in your question to help us reproduce your issue ;-)

Comment: Sorry friend. i changed my coding as per yours. Please see above and tell where i made mistake

Answer (score 0):

changeDefaultText replaces the default text by the selected value.

**JS**

```
var vm = {
    selected :  ko.observable(), 
    items : ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    defaultText:  ko.observable('Default text'),
    changeDefaultText : function(){
        vm.defaultText(vm.selected());
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

**View**

```
<select  data-bind="options: items, optionsCaption: defaultText, value : selected"></select>

<button data-bind="click : changeDefaultText">ChangeDefaultText</button>
```

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5gr7S/6/)

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Damien, thanks for your reply, but your code is not working in fiddle.. Please check and re write for me.

Comment: Can you explain what is not working ? What are you expecting ? Because when I click the button the default text changes.

Comment: Yes. it changed. but its not showing that text as selected text. I want to show that text as selected text. Please help me

Comment: So you want to change the value and not the default text.

Comment: No no... After User selected option in that dropdown, click refresh button then it will show selected text as 'Choose..'. Your code is changing the text but it not showing the text as selected one. Please help me friends

Comment: Hi Damien, really thanks for your reply. But i said wrongly to you i think. What I want is dropdown having option 'Choose..','a','b','c'. Suppose user select option text 'b' and click refresh button, then it will show selected option text as 'Choose..' without reloading the page.. please help me friend

Answer (score 0):

Just bind your `<select>` to observable variable and set its value to null to unselect any item.

```
<select id="ddlClassificationPosition" name="" data-theme="c" data-bind="options: ClassificationPositionData, value: selectedPosition, optionsValue: 'ClassificationPositionID', optionsText: function (i) { return i.Classification + ':' + i.Position }, optionsCaption: 'Choose..'"></select>

<button data-bind="click: function(){ $root.selectedPosition(null); }">Reset</button>
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Wuj98/

Comment: Hi f_marinez, thanks for your reply ..I want to clear few textbox values in that button click. but your code is only for fix text option in select. Could you please re-write code for me?

Comment: @Giri, could you show your complete viewmodel and data bindings for text boxes?

Comment: texboxes ah?? I'm looking solution for set 'Choose..' text as selected text when button click

Comment: @Giri, "I want to clear few textbox values in that button click. but your code is only for fix text option in select."

Comment: Oh sorry friend. Yes I had three textboxes with one select option. While refresh button, i want to clear textbox values and make select option text as "Choose..".. so please give solution for my problem

Comment: Certainly it's an option to solve your problem with jQuery if your textboxes are NOT bound against any data in model. But if they ARE bound then the solution will be very different and probably more efficient. Which an option are you interested in? Show your full field reset code pls.

Comment: I changed my code . please see above and tell me where i made mistake